# How can I read the DPI for a JPG file on Android?

Tags: android, jpeg, dpi

Is there a java library that can read the DPI from a jpg file ([like pngj for PNG](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/))? This is for code on the Android so I can't use java.awt.image.*

And if there's a way to do this with the Android Bitmap class, that would be awesome.

Comment: Why is it even needed? the DPI data is used for printing, not for screens. when you put the file into the resources folders, you decide what density to use for the image...

Comment: We are generating PDF files and we use the DPI to determine the size of the image on the page.

Comment: public static int dpToPixels(Context context, float dp) {
     final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
     return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
 }

Comment: maybe you can flip that around and use it somehow

Answer (score 0):

according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format), this is how jpeg metadata works :

first 2 bytes are 0xFFD8 (SOI as specified [here](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf)). then, if there is metadata, you get 0xFFE0 (2 bytes)

if there is metadata, there is the length segment(2 bytes) the identifier segment(5 bytes : 0x4A46494600) , then the version segment (2 bytes) , then the density:

density units are 1 byte: 0 for none specified, 1 for PPI, 2 for PPC .

then you get the x density (2 bytes) and the y density (2 bytes).

so , in short, you have to skip 2+2+2+5+2=13 bytes , read 1 byte for the type of density units, and if it's not 0 , read another 4 bytes for the density values (x and y) .

hope it can help.

---

i was curious to check it out, so i've made a nice snippet that worked for a sample jpg file. hope it would work for any file, as i haven't read the article so well:

```
final InputStream inputStream=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tt);
try
  {
  inputStream.skip(13);
  final int densityType=inputStream.read();
  switch(densityType)
    {
    case 0:
      Log.d("DEBUG","no density specified");
      break;
    case 1:
      Log.d("DEBUG","density in PPI");
      break;
    case 2:
      Log.d("DEBUG","density in PPC");
      break;
    }
  if(densityType!=0)
    {
    final byte[] densityValue=new byte[2];
    inputStream.read(densityValue);
    final int xDensity=(densityValue[0]<<8)+densityValue[1];
    inputStream.read(densityValue);
    final int yDensity=(densityValue[0]<<8)+densityValue[1];
    Log.d("DEBUG","xDensity:"+xDensity+" yDensity:"+yDensity);
    }
  }
catch(final IOException e)
  {}
try
  {
  inputStream.close();
  }
catch(final IOException e)
  {}
```

EDIT: i think the "length" bytes shouldn't be ignored as they represent the "Length of segment excluding APP0 marker" , so if it's too small, you can't read the density part and might read things that don't have anything to do with density.

i hope you do get the point though, and it's not so hard to fix my code.

Comment: Your sample code won't work for any JPEG file because the jpeg tags can come in any order and you make a bad assumption about the position of the data. The APP0 marker does contain density (DPI) information, but it's usually invalid.

Comment: well that's why i wrote that if you find anything wrong, please let me know what to change in order to fix it. since i'm not an expert in how jpeg are written (and most of the file types), all i did is read from some websites and write a sample code. if you know how to fix the code please tell me .

Comment: I basically already gave you the answer. You need to walk the chain of JPEG tags and find FFE0. Then the code will work on all JPEG files.

Comment: how do you walk the chain of the tags? by reading 2 bytes each time till you get to FFE0 ? should i also check the "length" parameter (as i wrote in the answer) ? what if the metadata doesn't exist? is there a default metadata to look at?

Comment: contact me directly and I'll send you some code. SO comments are not the place for my answer.

Comment: if there are a lot of things, you can use http://snipt.org/ or any other website.